# cocos2d collision detection BOOL Flag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am really trying to get my head round collision detection, here are my game details:
I have a character that can move freely around the screen and fire bullets
Enemies are generated off screen and the ‘hero’ can shoot them (when bullets and enemies are created they are stored in arrays and then removed at collision)
Currently if the enemy makes contact with the hero then nothing happens, I would like a life to be removed on contact and believe this is done via collision detection.
I am using

```
(CGRectIntersectsRect([hero boundingBox], [enemy boundingBox]))
```

But not all collisions are detected and then suddenly 3 will detected. I believe that this is caused as multiple collisions are detected  as the objects pass through each other. I have tried to use a BOOL flag to but I don’t believe that I am doing it correctly, my code:

```
.h
BOOL collision;
.m
-(void)update:(ccTime)deltaTime {    
    if (collision == NO) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([hero boundingBox], [enemy boundingBox])) {
            CCLOG(@”collision detected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!”);
            collision = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to deal with collision detection and if so how do you implement the BOOL flag?

Comment: I do not understand your question, could you clarify what you want to achieve and what is the problem? Also clarify is the posted code is your original misbehaving code or your unsuccessful attempt to fix the problem. If it's not your original code, post it as well.

Comment: @Ricardo Sánchez-Sáez Hi, I have changed the description to hopefully make this clearer, I am just really trying to figure out collision detection and the best way to do this.

Comment: I should have been more specific regarding what I didn't understand. What do you mean by "But not all collisions are detected and then suddenly 3 will (be) detected"? Could you also describe your *expected bahavior* compared the *current behavior* in a simple broken-down way? If I had to guess: "you want to detect only the first collision and avoid detecting any further collision for each frame". Is this correct? If that's the case your code looks good, buy you need to set `collision = NO` at the beginning of each frame (before the `if`) so the collision state variable resets.

Answer (score 1):

You just set the boolean on yes when you collide and no when you stop colliding so that you know next time when it's a new collision.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([hero boundingBox], [enemy boundingBox])) {
    CCLOG(@”collision detected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!”);
    if(!collision) {
        // REMOVE LIFE
    }
    collision = YES;
}
else {
    collision = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool property for your enemy object and set it false on enemy's init method.
When collision will be detected set its value to true and in your update method check something like this:

```
if (enemy.isCollide)
 {
    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect([hero boundingBox], [enemy boundingBox])) 
    {
       enemy.isCollide = No;
    }
 }
else
 {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect([hero boundingBox], [enemy boundingBox])) {
    enemy.isCollide = Yes; }
 }
```